# Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment Can't find issues at that line though

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am just completely lost at this point. This is my first major attempt at fragments i probably have screwed this up somehow. I am following along with a textbook, but its written for eclipse so some of the stuff does not line up so well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

LogCat

```
02-26 17:34:20.841    2105-2105/edu.wmich.lab2aricha9157 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: edu.wmich.lab2aricha9157, PID: 2105
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.wmich.lab2aricha9157/edu.wmich.lab2aricha9157.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
        at edu.wmich.lab2aricha9157.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
```

Here is my main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//Shared preference keys
public static final String CHOICES = "pref_numberOfChoices";
public static final String GENRES = "pref_genresToInclude";

//This boolean is here to be used for forcing portrait mode if the user is on a small screen
private boolean phoneDevice = true;
private boolean preferencesChanged = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // set action as the default genre with 3 choices
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);

    //initialize the shared preference listener
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener);

    // figure out what type of device they are using
    int screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;

    // if it has a large screen, like a tablet or fablet phone device will be set to false
    if (screenSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE || screenSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE ) {
        phoneDevice = false; //when its false it will use landscape mode for fablets and tablets
    }
    // if it is a phone or small device use portrait mode
    if (phoneDevice) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }


}//end onCreate

protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    if (preferencesChanged)
    {

        // launch the game fragment to the main activity
        GameFragment gameFragment = (GameFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.gameFragment);
        //update the settings from shared preferences for number of guess's
        gameFragment.updateGuessRows(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this));
        //do the same for the selected genres
        gameFragment.updateGenres(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this));
        //reset the quiz with the new settings
        gameFragment.resetQuiz();
        //
        preferencesChanged = false;
    }
}



private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener preferenceChangeListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()
        {
            // called when the user changes the app's preferences
            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
            {
                preferencesChanged = true;

                GameFragment gameFragment = (GameFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.gameFragment);

                if (key.equals(CHOICES)) // set the number of answers they can pick from
                {
                    gameFragment.updateGuessRows(sharedPreferences);
                    gameFragment.resetQuiz();
                }
                // change the genres included
                else if (key.equals(GENRES))
                {
                    Set<String> genres = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(GENRES, null);

                    if (genres != null && genres.size() > 0)
                    {
                        gameFragment.updateGenres(sharedPreferences);
                        gameFragment.resetQuiz();
                    }
                    else // if they don't select a genre action will be set by default
                    {
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        genres.add(getResources().getString(R.string.default_genre));
                        editor.putStringSet(GENRES, genres);
                        editor.commit();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,R.string.default_genre_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.restarting_quiz, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } // end method onSharedPreferenceChanged
        }; // sharedpreference change listener




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



 public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri){

 }

}
```

And my the fragment

```
public class GameFragment extends Fragment {


private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

// Store logged error messages
private static final String TAG = "GameFragment Activity";

//number of games in the quiz
private static final int GAMES_IN_QUIZ = 6;

// game file list
private List<String> fileNameList;
//games in the quiz
private List<String> quizGamesList;
//genres in the quiz
private Set<String> genreSet;
//correct answer
private String correctAnswer;
//number of guesses
private int totalGuesses;
//number that are correct
private int correctAnswers;
//number of rows that show the answer buttons
private int guessRows;
//randomize the games in the quiz
private SecureRandom random;
//delay loading the next screen shot
private Handler handler;
//animation that runs when you are wrong
private Animation wrongAnswerAnimation;
//current question number
private TextView TextViewQuestionNumber;
//shows the screen shot
private ImageView ImageViewGame;
//number of answer buttons
private LinearLayout[] guessLinearLayouts;
//feedback to teh user if they are right or wrong
private TextView TextViewAnswer;




@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game, container, false);

    fileNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    quizGamesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    random = new SecureRandom();
    handler = new Handler();

    // run the animation
    wrongAnswerAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.wrong_answer_animation);
    //repeat it 5 times
    wrongAnswerAnimation.setRepeatCount(5);

    // connect to the xml
    TextViewQuestionNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextViewQuestionNumber);
    ImageViewGame = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ImageViewGame);
    guessLinearLayouts = new LinearLayout[3];
    guessLinearLayouts[0] = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.row1LinearLayout);
    guessLinearLayouts[1] = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.row2LinearLayout);
    guessLinearLayouts[2] = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.row3LinearLayout);
    TextViewAnswer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextViewAnswer);

    // listeners for the answer buttons
    for (LinearLayout row : guessLinearLayouts) {
        for (int column = 0; column < row.getChildCount(); column++) {
            Button button = (Button) row.getChildAt(column);
            button.setOnClickListener(guessButtonListener);
        }
    }

    // set the text for each question
    TextViewQuestionNumber.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.question, 1, GAMES_IN_QUIZ));
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;

}


public void updateGuessRows(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences)
{
    // get the preference for number of choices
    String choices = sharedPreferences.getString(MainActivity.CHOICES, null);

        guessRows = Integer.parseInt(choices) / 3;

    // hide the answer buttons
    for (LinearLayout layout : guessLinearLayouts) {
        layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    // display the answer buttons
    for (int row = 0; row < guessRows; row++) {
        guessLinearLayouts[row].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

//updates the genres in the quiz from shared prefs
public void updateGenres(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences)
{
    genreSet = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(MainActivity.GENRES, null);
}


public void resetQuiz()
{
    // get the images from the asset manager
    AssetManager assets = getActivity().getAssets();
    //clear the list of images
    fileNameList.clear();

    try
    {
        // loop for each genre
        for (String genre : genreSet)
        {
            // get the list of genres
            String[] paths = assets.list(genre);

            for (String path : paths) {
                fileNameList.add(path.replace(".png", ""));
            }
        }
    }
    //error catching for the images
    catch (IOException exception)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error loading image file names", exception);
    }

    //reset the guess count
    totalGuesses = 0;
    // reset the correct answer count
    correctAnswers = 0;
    //clear the game list
    quizGamesList.clear();

    int gameCounter = 1;
    int numberOfGames = fileNameList.size();

    // add a new list of random games
    while (gameCounter <= GAMES_IN_QUIZ)
    {
        int randomIndex = random.nextInt(numberOfGames);

        // pull the file at random
        String fileName = fileNameList.get(randomIndex);

        // checks to see if the genre is active but not used
        if (!quizGamesList.contains(fileName))
        {
            // if so its added in
            quizGamesList.add(fileName);
            ++gameCounter;
        }
    }

    loadNextGame();
} // end resetQuiz

private void loadNextGame()
{
    // pulls a game name then removes if from the list so it doesn't get added twice
    String nextImage = quizGamesList.remove(0);
    //set the correct answer
    correctAnswer = nextImage;
    //clear the text view
    TextViewAnswer.setText("");


    TextViewQuestionNumber.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.question,(correctAnswers + 1), GAMES_IN_QUIZ));

    // get the genre from the image name
    String genre = nextImage.substring(0, nextImage.indexOf('-'));

    // use AssetManager to get next image from assets
    AssetManager assets = getActivity().getAssets();

    try
    {
        // get an InputStream to load the next image
        InputStream stream = assets.open(genre + "/" + nextImage + ".png");

        // load it as a drawable the user the imageview to display it
        Drawable game = Drawable.createFromStream(stream, nextImage);
        ImageViewGame.setImageDrawable(game);
    }
    catch (IOException exception)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error loading " + nextImage, exception);
    }

    // shuffle the files list
    Collections.shuffle(fileNameList);

    // sort the correct answer
    int correct = fileNameList.indexOf(correctAnswer);
    fileNameList.add(fileNameList.remove(correct));

    // add the chosen number of guess rows
    for (int row = 0; row < guessRows; row++)
    {
        // place the buttons in the layout
        for (int column = 0;
             column < guessLinearLayouts[row].getChildCount(); column++)
        {

            Button newGuessButton = (Button) guessLinearLayouts[row].getChildAt(column);
            newGuessButton.setEnabled(true);

            // get the game name and set it as the buttons text
            String fileName = fileNameList.get((row * 3) + column);
            newGuessButton.setText(getGameName(fileName));
        }
    }

    // set one ofthe buttons to be correct at random
    int row = random.nextInt(guessRows);
    int column = random.nextInt(3);
    LinearLayout randomRow = guessLinearLayouts[row];
    String gameName = getGameName(correctAnswer);
    ((Button) randomRow.getChildAt(column)).setText(gameName);
} // end loadNextGame

private String getGameName(String name)
{
    //makes the image name easier to read
    return name.substring(name.indexOf('-') + 1).replace('_', ' ');
}

private View.OnClickListener guessButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Button guessButton = ((Button) v);
        String guess = guessButton.getText().toString();
        String answer = getGameName(correctAnswer);
        ++totalGuesses;

        //what to do when the user is correct
        if (guess.equals(answer))
        {
            //add one to the correct answer count
            ++correctAnswers;

            // show the correct answer
            TextViewAnswer.setText(answer + "!");
            TextViewAnswer.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.right_answer));

            //disable the buttons
            disableButtons();


            if (correctAnswers == GAMES_IN_QUIZ)
            {

                DialogFragment quizResults = new DialogFragment()
                        {
                            // create the alert
                            @Override
                            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle bundle)
                            {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                                builder.setCancelable(false);

                                builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.results, totalGuesses, (1000 / (double) totalGuesses)));

                                // button to reset the game
                                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.reset_quiz,
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                                        {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                                            {
                                                resetQuiz();
                                            }
                                        }
                                );

                                return builder.create(); // return the Alert
                            } // endonCreateDialog
                        }; // end DialogFragment

                // use FragmentManager to display the DialogFragment
                quizResults.show(getFragmentManager(), "results");
            }
            else
            {
                // load the next game image
                handler.postDelayed(
                        new Runnable()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void run()
                            {
                                loadNextGame();
                            }
                        }, 2000); // 2000 milliseconds for 2-second delay
            }
        }
        else // guess was wrong
        {
            ImageViewGame.startAnimation(wrongAnswerAnimation);

            // display wrong answer message
            TextViewAnswer.setText(R.string.incorrect_answer);
            TextViewAnswer.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.wrong_answer));
            //disable the button they have already tried
            guessButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    } // end onClick
}; // end answerButtonListener

// disables all answer Buttons
private void disableButtons()
{
    for (int row = 0; row < guessRows; row++)
    {
        LinearLayout guessRow = guessLinearLayouts[row];
        for (int i = 0; i < guessRow.getChildCount(); i++)
            guessRow.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);
    }
}







// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p/>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}//end GameFragment
```

**fragment_game**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewQuestionNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/question"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageViewGame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_description"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewGuessGame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/guess_game"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row1LinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row2LinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="invisible" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row3LinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="invisible" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewAnswer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="@dimen/answer_size"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You crashed on setContentView(). Pls post your activity_main xml file.

Comment: Added it to the the original comment

Comment: I think the issue is at GameFragment.java or fragment_game,xml. Please post that xml also. If you think the xml is valid, then GameFragment code has to be debugged. Meantime let's see fragment_game,xml

Comment: This may be an opinion, but your onCreateView should be much simpler. It is doing too much. If you agree, then we can discuss options, and there are.

Comment: I added fragment_game. I really appreciate you taking the time to check out my code.

Comment: Where is activity_main xml file? I thought you already posted this. Basically I may have to import your code into mine. This would speed up progress. The more related code and xml, the better. Hiding code or whatever doesn't help in this blog.

Comment: I suspect you crashed on GameFragment.java and you may have to debug the code and tell me what line of code is the problem. If/when we get to that point, then we can think of fixes.